# Is there a way to obtain old Salmon Run clothing?

Tags: splatoon-2

I’ve been playing a lot of salmon run lately. I started playing a few months ago and didn’t know about Salmon run till now. I’ve seen many people that have the old prizes from salmon run and I would like to know if there is anyway I could obtain them?

Answer (score 3):

### Pink Capsules!

As you earn points doing salmon runs, you'll unlock various capsules (and the latest piece of Grizzco gear). Go to the window to the left of the entrance to the Salmon Run lobby, and you'll be able to obtain the reward from all your earned capsules.

[Per the Wiki:](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Salmon_Run#Rewards)

- Blue Capsules: Drink Tickets
- Green Capsules: Ability Chunks
- Orange Capsules: Multiplier Tickets
- Pink Capsules: Grizzco Gear
- Yellow Capsules: Cash

(Note that all capsules besides the pink capsule have a 50% chance of containing 4000 gold rather than their standard reward, pink capsules will always contain a piece of gear)

The pink capsules will contain a random piece of Grizzco gear (with either 0, 1, or 3 slots filled), and includes all previous pieces of gear.